# GPIO pin error?

Tags: raspbian, python

I am trying to have a magnetic door sensor be detected after every time it connects and disconnects. I have looked at [this](https://medium.com/conectric-networks/playing-with-raspberry-pi-door-sensor-fun-ab89ad499964) as a guide, but I am stuck at on part when compiling.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "sensor_test.py", line 9, in 
>       pin.DOOR_SENSOR_PIN = 18
>   NameError: name 'pin' is not defined

My code looks like this

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
import signal


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pin.DOOR_SENSOR_PIN = 18

isOpen = None
oldIsOpen = None

GPIO.setup(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
   oldIsOpen = isOpen
   isOpen = GPIO.input(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN)

isOpen = None
oldIsOpen = None

GPIO.setup(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
oldIsOpen = isOpen
isOpen = GPIO.input(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN)

if(isOpen and (isOpen != oldIsOpen)):
elif(isOpen != oldIsOpen):
    print "Sensor is connected"
    #sock.send("open")
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Most errors I've read says that the "import RPi.GPIO as GPIO" is missing or the setmode is missing, but I have both of those. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you remove `pin.` from the code

Comment: >'DOOR_SENSOR_PIN' is not defined

Comment: The page you referenced is just poorly formatted html. the "pin.' is part of the comment on the previous line. There are plenty of well written tutorials. NOTE that if you are copying code you should also include the comments - they are there for a reason! You can't just delete lines of code e.g. after `if(isOpen and (isOpen != oldIsOpen)):`

Comment: You would be better to start with [gpiozero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/python/README.md)

Comment: @LoganVanderbeck - I didn't mean **that whole line** ... I said *remove `pin.`* - so remove exactly what I said to remove

Answer (score 3):

Skip the `pin.` so that

```
pin.DOOR_SENSOR_PIN = 18
```

turns into

```
DOOR_SENSOR_PIN = 18
```

because that is just what is needed and what is used further down the script, e.g.:

```
# here
GPIO.setup(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
# here
isOpen = GPIO.input(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN)
# and here
GPIO.setup(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

`DOOR_SENSOR_PIN` is just supposed to be a constant that prevents you from putting a magic number (18) in every statement where it is used - which is error prone once you start changing it. This way you change it once and be done.